# How we can get Site working in Sandbox environment

Tags: sandbox

I have a sandbox environment, now I have created a site with blank domain name, after that when I dynamically generate the site link through Apex but I am unable to access sandbox name. Please suggest how we can do that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you need to use [URL Class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_url.htm#apex_System_URL_getSalesforceBaseUrl)

```
String sfdcBaseURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
```

Comment: https://[SANDBOX-NAME].[SITE-SUBDOMAIN-NAME].[INSTANCE-NAME].force.com
Now, how we can get sandbox name dynamically as we can get other things dynamically.